# Is it possible to read big xlsx files in PHP?

Tags: php, excel, xlsx

I have big xlsx file (16 000 rows and 14 columns), I tried to use PHPExcel to read it, but I got error: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 58 bytes) in Z:\home\xlsx.qqq\www\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php on line 961`.

Is it possible to read big xlsx file in php without such errors?

Thanx!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Excel Allowed Memory size exhausted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560053/phpexcel-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted)

Comment: and more generally: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Allowed+memory+size+of+134217728+bytes+exhausted

Answer (score 1):

Use PHPExcel cell caching system - you can find more in the documentation file included in the download package.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options. Either increase PHP's memory limit so that the entire file can be read into memory at once or read the file incrementally.