# phpExcel how do I pass settings into class

Tags: php, caching, memory-leaks, phpexcel

Basically im trying to enable cell caching due to memory issues (keeps running out) its quite a large speadsheet.  From what I have read online cell caching is a good way to go

From the examples I have found online it looks something like this

[Cell caching and memory leak](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/234530)

[stackoverflow - fix memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537604/how-to-fix-a-memory-error-in-php)

```
$oExcel = new PHPExcel();
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize' => '512MB');

PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod,$cacheSettings);
```

The problem with the above is im not setting the excel object with the settings?

```
$oExcel->setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod,$cacheSettings); // this returns method not found error
```

I think im just initialising it wrong?

Comment: So docs say `setCacheStorageMethod` is static?

Comment: cant find reference to it in the docs. However found this is discussion.
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/234530

Comment: [Here you can find similar question with quite extensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3539125/2028547) that includes a working example of <kbd>setCacheStorageMethod</kbd>. Hope it helps!

Comment: With docs I meant wherever you read the `PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod,$cacheSettings);` bit. It's displayed as static method of the `PHPExcel_Settings` class, not a regular method of the `PHPExcel` class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's described in section 4.2.1 of the developer documentation: the section entitled "Cell Caching"; and you need to set the cell cache **before** you instantiate or load your PHPExcel object.

setCacheStorageMethod() is not a method of the PHPExcel class, as you're trying to use in this line:

```
$oExcel->setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod,$cacheSettings);
```

use

```
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize' => '512MB');
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod,$cacheSettings);

$oExcel = new PHPExcel();
```

and the new PHPExcel object will automatically use the configured cache setting (ie phptemp)

Comment: For the above to work does the new initializing of new PHPExcel() have to happen after the setCache static method has been ran.  I'm a bit confused how the object is aware of the new setting.

Comment: Yes, afterwards.... the PHPExcel object constructor reads the cache settings that you have defined previously