# How to close excel file in php-excel-reader

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am reading two excel file, using php-excel-reader ([From this)](https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/downloads/list)

After reading two files of 1st row, I am comparing it. If they are same then I am appending contain of on file to other. To write the file I am using [this](http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2009/12/15/how-to-create-excel-files-in-php/)

Now for doing this I want to close one file, but that function is not available in  php-excel-reader

here is my code

```
compare file

{

$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($filepath);

$data1 = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($destinationfilepath);

}

unset($data);

unset($data1);


if($flag==0)
{

$excel = new ExcelWriter($destinationfilepath); 

// read the source file

 $finalarray= array();

for($m=1;$m<$sourcefilerowcount;$m++)

    { 

           $charvalue='A';

             $temprow=$m+1;

              for($n=0;$n<$destinationcolnum;$n++)
        {

            $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($filepath);

                            $finalarray[$n]=$data->val($temprow,$charvalue);

                            $charvalue++;

                    }

             print_r($finalarray)."<br/>";

     $excel->writeLine($finalarray);
  }
```

Comment: Its in the code i guess `$excel->close();` [http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2009/12/15/how-to-create-excel-files-in-php/](http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2009/12/15/how-to-create-excel-files-in-php/)

Comment: ya.but for php-excel-reader i am not getting.                     $data1 = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($destinationfilepath); how to close $data1 ?

Comment: @2492230 you can use `unset($data1);`

Comment: thank you.i tried this one. but my data is not copying in other file.i will upload my code

Comment: @user2492230 Show us your code, that is not working and explain, what you are trying to achieve there

Comment: @user2492230 Remove the unset line. If you want, you can put  in the end of the script code, working with $data. There is no need to close the files explicitly - phpExcelReader is doing it for you. Why do you want to close? Isn't anything working correctly?

Comment: @ user4035: first time i m opening that file header reading to compare the headers with some other file header suppose if both file hearde are match then i have to copy the data from one file to another. so first time opening the file to read the hearers in read mode and i want to close file in and then i want to open this file in write mode. so i want to close it. because it is not allowing me to write in to file because it is already open so i have to close that first then only i can open the same in write mode.

Comment: Rather than using two different and incompatible packages for reading Excel and for writing Excel, why not look for a single package that can both read and write Excel files.... like the PHPExcel package that you've listed in your tags

Comment: @user2492230 Use 1 package to read and write as Mark Baker said.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to explicitly call close() function, because the file is automatically closed in the load() method. If you look at Excel2007.php, where PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007 is defined, you'll see:

```
public function load($pFilename)
{
    ...
    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    $zip->open($pFilename);
    ...
    $zip->close();
    return $excel;
}
```

Just unset your PHPExcel_Reader object, and the data will be removed from memory:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2003XML');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("Excel2003XMLTest.xml");
...
unset($objPHPExcel);
unset($objReader);
```

Comment: OP Isn't actually using PHPExcel, despite the tag; they're using PEAR SEW.... though the same argument holds: PEAR SEW closes the file after loading the file into memory

Comment: @MarkBaker Ahh, I missed it - was misguided by the tag. Yeah, he should use the same lib everywhere.