# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 78 bytes)

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a problem with memory in PHPExcel

This is the error message:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 78 bytes) in /home/***/public_html/system/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/CachedObjectStorage/Memory.php on line 55

This is my `php.ini`:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
register_globals = Off;
default_charset = UTF-8;
memory_limit = 4096M;
max_execution_time = 36000;
upload_max_filesize = 4096M;
post_max_size = 4096M;
safe_mode = Off;
mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
session.use_only_cookies = On;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.cookie_httponly = On;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 172800;
allow_url_fopen = on;
;display_errors = 1;
;error_reporting = E_ALL;
```

I am a newbie in PHP. Please help me, thanks very much.

Comment: Is your Excel file bigger than 4GB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPExcel runs out of 256, 512 and also 1024MB of RAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817651/phpexcel-runs-out-of-256-512-and-also-1024mb-of-ram)

Comment: Obviously your memory limit settings in php.ini didn't take effect, since PHP is saying the limit is 64meg (67,108,864 bytes). Did you restart PHP/webserver after changing the .ini file? Did you check if there's a memory_limit setting ELSEWHERE that's overriding the .ini version?

Comment: Also look at [this](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/242712?ProjectName=phpexcel) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537604/how-to-fix-a-memory-error-in-php)

Comment: So read the section of the documentation about [cell caching](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md)

Comment: @Justinas : size of excel file is 451kb

Comment: @MarcB: I call the function echo ini_get('memory_limit'); the result is 4096M. Is there other way to check memory limit setting?

Comment: @user: obviously it's not, because your error says the limit is 64meg.

Answer (score 0):

You can set bigger memory limit (atm it is ~64 MB, 67.11 MB)

To overrides the default PHP memory limit :

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

Remove limit

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Comment: Be aware that if you have a memory leak, you should fix it first.

Comment: The script : ini_get('memory_limit') => result = 4096M

Comment: I goto cpanel, I see memory_limit = -1

Comment: Seems like it is a cache memory problem.