# Timeout error (500) when reading a xlsx file using Laravel Excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I am getting this timeout error when I try to read xlsx files using Laravel Excel. Xls files work fine though. 
I increased memory limit in `php.ini` but it still returns the same error. 
Note that this doesn't happen in my local machine, only on the shared server that I use for prod and test. 
I found a topic on stack overflow that recommends some settings to decrease memory consumption by activating caching and other things (link: [How to fix memory getting exhausted with PHPExcel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537604/how-to-fix-memory-getting-exhausted-with-phpexcel) ).

However this thread is for PHP Excel. Even though Laravel Excel is a PHP Excel child I don't know how to access the corresponding configuration.

Comment: Be aware about some limitations shared servers has. I't seem's a process execution time more than limit memory usage , try to add the set_time_limit(0); directive ...

Answer (score 0):

`php.ini` isn't in effect until the server is restarted, and if that's a shared server you won't be able to restart the server yourself.
Contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and for this I created a lib that only does the import and returns an array with all the content of the file, is much faster than the laravel excel and does not have this problem try to use it in development can change what I want to, if you want, I'll put anyone who wants to help as a git contributor.

[lib on gitHub](https://github.com/fastreading/excel)