# PHPExcel Allowed memory size of exhausted

Tags: php, excel, memory, out-of-memory

I'm creating big excel file with images, and now i have this problem. Without images all works good. 
In addition to this, i can't increase memory limit.

What should i do?
I can't find real code examples, i've heard about reader but i don't understand how to use it right.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $sheet->setCellValue("A".$i, $value['articul']);
    $sheet->setCellValue("B".$i, $value['text']);

    //uploading image to my server

    $type_img = explode( ".",$value['image']);
    $type_img =  ".".end($type_img);
    $pht_lnk = $value['image'];
    $photoname = explode("/", $value['image']);
    $photoname = end($photoname);
    $dir_upl = 'img/'.$photoname;
    if (!fileExists($dir_upl)) {
        if(file_put_contents($dir_upl, file_get_contents($pht_lnk))) { 
            $imagePath = $dir_upl;
        }
        else{
            $imagePath = NULL;
        }
    }
    else{
        $imagePath = $dir_upl;
    }

    //here i'm trying to add image

    if (file_exists($imagePath)) {
        $imgg = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
        $imgg->setPath($imagePath);
        $imgg->setCoordinates("C".$i);             
        $imgg->setOffsetX(0);
        $imgg->setOffsetY(0);    
        $sheet->getRowDimension(2)->setRowHeight(190);
        $imgg->setWorksheet($sheet);
    } 
    $sheet->setCellValue("D".$i, $value['price']);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Is the file size too big or is the script running out of memory?

Comment: @El_Vanja i think script running

Comment: Can you lose the PHPExcel library? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537604/how-to-fix-memory-getting-exhausted-with-phpexcel) suggests it has serious memory issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cant increase memory limit try another libs

[PHP-Export-Data](https://github.com/elidickinson/php-export-data/blob/master/php-export-data.class.php) by Eli Dickinson

[simple excel](http://faisalman.github.io/simple-excel-php/)

[PHP_XLSXWriter](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter)